# Swift string to date

Tags: swift

I'm trying to convert string "2020-04-05T16:00:00Z" to date in Swift. I'm using following code:

```
extension String {
    var iso8601Date: Date? {
        Formatter.iso8601Formatter.date(from: self)
    }
}

extension Formatter {
    static let iso8601Formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter([.withInternetDateTime])
}

extension ISO8601DateFormatter {
    convenience init(_ formatOptions: Options, timeZone: TimeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0) ?? .current) {
        self.init()
        self.formatOptions = formatOptions
        self.timeZone = timeZone
    }
}
```

This conversion takes 100ms (per 1000 iteration) on emulator, and 70ms on device. Is there a way to do this conversion faster? Thanks.

Comment: Did you compile in Release mode when you benchmarked?

Comment: No, unless you write your own, faster `ISO8601DateFormatter`... Are you sure there aren't _other_ aspects of your code that you can improve? Use Instruments to find out if you haven't already.

Comment: The `Formatter` and `ISO8601DateFormatter` extensions are pointless. The default initializer `ISO8601DateFormatter()` does the same